# GMAT Sun Ephemeris Output

Tags: the-sun, ephemeris, gmat, position

I need the sun's position vector for an analysis, conducted in Matlab.

Thus, I let output the ephemeris files for the spacecrafts and additionally I would like to do the same with the sun.

A Report file is not an option, as the integrator step size varys from iteration to iteration. And setting the stepsize to a fixed value is not good practice, and time costy in the propagation.

So my question is: How do I output the ephemeris file of the sun from a GMAT propagation, as you can easily do with the spacecrafts?

I would highly appreciate help here!

Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In the end I just did it with a report file and fixed step size. It is still okay for shorter simulation periods.

Cheers!